# I'm confused about OAuth / Facebook process

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I've followed the instructions on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#authorization using the standard PHP library. Everything works fine until it redirects to my site. I'm not sure what I'm meant to be doing here! When the redirection occurs, I can see the key facebook talks about that I use to request an OAuth token in the URL.

However what am I meant to do with this? Do I write a simple script that takes the new 'code' value and place a request to the facebook page with that included in the details? Is there no call in the php library to do this entire process for me?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how the code looks in my application (simplified for this example)

```
$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
if ( $code )
{
  $response = $facebook->api( '/oauth/access_token', 'GET', array(
      'client_id'     => $facebook->getAppId()
    , 'client_secret' => $facebook->getApiSecret()
    , 'redirect_uri'  => 'http://example.com/your/redirect/uri'
    , 'code'          => $code
  ) );
  parse_str( $response, $vars );
  $oauthToken = $vars['access_token'];

  // Persist this token in the session, DB, or wherever you want

} else {
  switch ( $_REQUEST['error_reason'] )
  {
    case 'user_denied':
      // some sort of message here
      break;
  }
}
```

If, like me, you have created a subclass of `Facebook`, just put some of the above into a new method

```
/**
 * Exchange an Access Code for an OAuth Token
 *  
 * @param string $accessCode
 * @param string $redirectUrl
 * 
 * @return string OAuth Token
 */
public function getOauthTokenFromAccessCode( $accessCode, $redirectUrl )
{
  $response = $this->api( '/oauth/access_token', 'GET', array(
      'client_id'     => $this->getAppId()
    , 'client_secret' => $this->getApiSecret()
    , 'redirect_uri'  => $redirectUrl
    , 'code'          => $accessCode
  ) );
  parse_str( $response, $vars );
  return $vars['access_token'];
}
```

Which simplifies the client code to this

```
$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
if ( $code )
{
  $oauthToken = $facebook->getOauthTokenFromAccessCode(
      $code
    , 'http://example.com/your/redirect/uri'
  );

  // Persist this token in the session, DB, or wherever you want

} else {
  switch ( $_REQUEST['error_reason'] )
  {
    case 'user_denied':
      // some sort of message here
      break;
  }
}
```